# How to disable particular item in a drop down element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you disable some items of a drop down element using jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: to disable , to not be shown or they must not be selected but visible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way you would disable any other HTML element, use

```
$(/* option selector */).prop('disabled', true);
```

See it in [action](http://jsfiddle.net/tusbar/vUEks/).

Comment: For the disabled property `.prop()` is not a bad way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Easy!

```
<select>
  <option value="Opt 1.">Opt 1.</option>
  <option class="optionselector" value="Opt 2. I'm disabled!" disabled="disabled">opt 2. I'm disabled!</option>
</select>
```

Simply append `disabled="disabled"` in the tag.

To do it in jQuery, make sure you've got the latest version loaded, then use the .attr() javascript to append the attribute `disabled="disabled"` as needed like so:

```
.click(function(){
    $('.optionselector').attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

Of course, you'll have to put .click inside of another event or function, so the .click is triggered by SOMETHING in particular, such as, this can be used to say "When I .click() this button, then add .attr()" etc.

Comment: The valves are unrelated, btw.

Comment: Thanks.

Can you tell me, how can i do this using javascript or jquery. Because I want to do this for certain conditions only(Not every time)

Comment: Ahhh... okay, I must've missed the jQuery part. I'll edit, 1 sec! :D

Comment: Not to be a stickler, but the attribute `disabled` is a [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled), not a string. What you've put will work because "disabled" is truthy, but it is technically an invalid value.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of jQuery, in plain js you get a reference to the option however and just set the disabled property to true. So given:

```
<form id="aForm" ...>
  <select name="aSelect">
    <option ...>zero
    <option ...>one
    <option ...>two
    <option ...>three
  </select>
  ...
</form>
```

then to disable all the options:

```
var options = document.forms['aForm']['aSelect'].options;
for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  options[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Of course you can disable just one based on whatever criterion you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
     $('#id').attr('disabled','disabled');          
})
```

and the html

```
<form id="fmname" method="get">

<select >
<option id="id">s</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: It will disable full drop down element. I want to disable few items only so that user will not be able to select those items

Comment: yes you can disable every element you want with this code $('#youroptionID').attr('disabled','disabled');

Answer (score 0):

```
$("option").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Just select needed options with another selector.