# How to disable items in asp dropdown list based on appointment times?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I just need the theory behind this if someone could explain. I have a dropdown list displaying 9-5. I have an appointment between 10-1pm - how do I go about disabling the times in the drop down to reflect this? Thank you in advance, examples welcome :)

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840200/how-to-disable-particular-item-in-a-drop-down-element

Comment: is it webforms or mvc ?

Answer (score -1):

Well You can Check each appointment with if condition,before this you need to iterate each dropdownlist items with foreach loop inside that you can check if condition,if condition meet you can disable it.